# unable to hide scrollbar with `overflow:none` and `-webkit-scrollbar`

Tags: html, css, iframe, scrollbar, overflow

I'm trying to hide the scrollbar for an iframe and it's not working. Here's my HTML:

```
<style>
.no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none
}

.no-scrollbar {
  overflow: none
}
</style>

<iframe class="no-scrollbar" id="iframe">zzz</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var doc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
   doc.open();
   doc.write('<body style="width: 110%">zzz</body>');
   doc.close();
</script>
```

Here's my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9a7k2dgn/

I can change it by changing the width to 90% (altho apparently not even 100% works; 90% does but not 100%) but, for the purposes of this example, let's assume that's not an option. And it's none-the-less my understanding that `overflow: none` should work regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll appeared is the scroll inside `iframe` content, not the scrollbar of `iframe` selector.

To hide this, you need to implement `overflow: hidden` on `iframe` body style as follows.

```
doc.write('<body style="width: 110%; overflow: hidden;">zzz</body>');
```